# How to use maven compiler plugin to pass arguments when launching HTTP server?

Tags: rest, maven, tomcat, jersey, arguments

I have RESTful web service with Java (Jersey/JAX-RS).

Is this possible to launch my server for this project like this:

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:run -additional params:"param1","param2"
```

using command line?

I want to use these parameters as variables in my program.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Pass arguments to what? Your main method? As  system properties? Please be more specific about where you want to access these variables.

Comment: I want to use these variables to specify data source url for my repository(it`s a file hosted on github). Is this even possible to use main method and String args[] in WebApi ?